# loading JQuery.js in my javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a js file say test.js and I want to import and use JQuery in it. I don't have a HTML file and I don't want to create one either.

I want to execute my js file once the jQuery is loaded. 
My code is as follows:

```
 var data = *some data that I am passing to the url*

function include(filename, onload) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = filename;
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
     script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (script.readyState) {
        if (script.readyState === 'complete' || script.readyState === 'loaded') {
            script.onreadystatechange = null;                                                  
            onload();
        }
    } 
    else {
        onload();          
    }
};
head.appendChild(script);
}

 include('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js', function() {
   $(document).ready(function() {
 $.ajax({
        url: "some url,
        type: 'POST',
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function(response) {
            var data = response.hits.total;
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function() {
          console.log("failed");
          }
       });

  });

});
```

This gives me an error :
"ReferenceError: document is not defined"

I am running my .js file in node.
How should I import and use JQuery.js to use it in my .js code?

Comment: nodejs has no concept of a document, have you tried making that call without the $(document).ready(..) ?

Comment: This seems wrong. Is your goal to make a http-request using node.js?

Comment: yes, its still throwing an error at line var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

Comment: My goals is to make http-request using JQuery and I am testing it using node

Comment: Question for the author... Why would you want to use jQuery when you don't even have an html page?

Comment: @JessevanderPluijm - Web-scraping for one. There are useful purposes. You can't just include jQuery, like you would on the client side, however. I would suggest using [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio).

Comment: OK, but wouldn't using jQuerry in node  be just as easy as telling your node file to **"require"** jquerry? I also found this: [nodeQuerry](https://github.com/tblobaum/nodeQuery).

Comment: Okay maybe I should have mentioned this earlier, I am trying to query Elasticsearch using DSL since my queries are pretty big. Hence using ajax but that needs JQuery

Comment: AJAX = [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like the `request` or `elasticsearch` modules (see npmjs.com).  Node.js is different from JavaScript in the browser, so the AJAX/jquery stuff doesn't apply.